# Stop camera from view going past background

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, unityscript

I've made my camera a child of the player but how do I stop the camera view going past the a background? I want to stop the blue bit from showing. My camera is orthographic.

I tried this

```
function Awake(){
    leftEdge = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1,0,0)).x;
    distToLeftEdge = renderer.bounds.size.x / 2;
}
if(transform.position.x + distToLeftEdge > leftEdge ){
    transform.position.x = leftEdge - distToLeftEdge;
    rigidbody2D.velocity.x = 0;
```

It didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You may be having problems due to the resolution/aspect ratio drop down being set to free aspect, this leads to a viewport that is wider than it would be if built and ran as an executable(If you're using "Maximize on Play").

[image: Highlighted drop down]

Try selecting a resolution/aspect ratio from the drop down list in the game window.

Here is a blog post(and a shameless plug) with some screenshots of before and after to illustrate what I perceive your problem being. Hope this helps.

http://www.lazr.pw/2014/06/unity-3d-blue-bars-on-sides-of.html

Also, you could extend your background image so that it overhangs your viewport so that it covers wider aspect ratios such as 16:10.